# Jcrop not cropping image correctly in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, jcrop

I'm using Asp.net MVC 4 and Jcrop jQuery Plugin to crop an image and after cropping, I'm uploading the cropped image to my server. Image is uploading successfully but the cropping area is not accurate as what was selected on the client side.

Here are my codes:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdminProfilePic(HttpPostedFileBase file, int Top, int Left, int Bottom, int Right)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        string picName = User.Identity.Name;
        WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
        string picExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        if (picExt == ".jpg" || picExt == ".gif" || picExt == ".jpeg" || picExt == ".png")
        {
            picExt = "PNG";
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Owners/"), picName);

            var img_cropped = img.Crop(Top, Left, Bottom, Right).Resize(160, 200, false, true);
            img_cropped.Save(path, picExt);
            img.Save(path, picExt);
            TempData["pp_success"] = "Your profile picture has been updated successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("AdminProfilePic");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["pp_fail"] = "Error! Please upload a valid image file only!";
            return RedirectToAction("AdminProfilePic");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["pp_fail"] = "Error! No File was selected!";
        return RedirectToAction("AdminProfilePic");
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdminProfilePic", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file01" style="width: 100%;" /><br />

    <img id="blah01" style="height: 350px;" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="your image" /><div id="cropper"></div>
    @Html.TextBox("Top", null, new { id = "Top" })<br />
    @Html.TextBox("Left", null, new { id = "Left" })<br />
    @Html.TextBox("Bottom", null, new { id = "Bottom" })<br />
    @Html.TextBox("Right", null, new { id = "Right" })<br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update Profile Picture" />
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showCoords(c) {
        $("#Top").val(c.x);
        $("#Left").val(c.y);
        $("#Bottom").val(c.x2);
        $("#Right").val(c.y2);
    }
    $('#blah01').Jcrop({
        onSelect: showCoords,
        bgColor: 'black',
        bgOpacity: .4,
        maxSize: [160, 200]
    });
});
```

Probably I'm not getting the accurate result because the real image size stays the same when uploading and the size of the image in the view won't count. So the selected cropped area co-ordinates are actually depending on the real image instead of the image given in the view. I've tried a lot but couldn't find any solution to resolve this. How can I get the accurate cropped image depending on the size of the image in the view?

### Update

As per Coulton's suggestion, I added these codes in my controller:

```
var myW = img.Width;
var myH = img.Height;
var Top = y;
var Left = x;
var Bottom = myH - y2;
var Right = myW - x2;
var img_cropped = img.Crop(Top, Left, Bottom, Right).Resize(160, 200, false, true);
```

**Screenshot**

Left side is the updated image after upload, and right side is the cropping section:

[image]

Comment: I assigned `x` to `top`, you're passing `y` to it..... `$("#Top").val(c.y);`

Answer (score 0):

The `WebImage` method `Crop()` expects the values `top, left, bottom, right`.

[According to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.crop(v=vs.111).aspx) these values represent how many pixels to *remove* from the top, left, bottom or right, whereas what you're passing in is the precise x, y, x2 and y2 coordinates that have been calculated based on the image, which is the number of pixels measured from the top left of the image.

They aren't the same thing, which is why you're experiencing strange cropping behaviour.

I don't know if `WebImage` has a method for the values that you get from JCrop.  I personally use [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org) for cropping images, this has a cropping method that accepts a the `top, left, width, height` instead.

I guess it would be possible to get the width and height of the image and perform calculations to transform the information that you have into the number of pixels to remove from the top, left, bottom and right.

Below is a bit of code that I've thrown together in order to perform the calculation of the values from `x, y, x2, y2` to the number of pixels to remove from the `top, left, bottom, right`:

```
public ActionResult AdminProfilePic(HttpPostedFileBase file, int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
    var img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);

    // Get the image height and width
    var width = img.Width;
    var height = img.Height;

    // Calculate the cropping values
    var top = y;
    var left = x;
    var bottom = height - y2;
    var right = width - x2;

    // Do the crop
    var img_cropped = img.Crop(top, left, bottom, right).Resize(160, 200, false, true);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about that. But I'm unable to figure out how to do the calculation. Really need to know how to do the calculation.

Comment: I've posted some additional code.  I've changed the overload of the action result and then created code to do the calculations that you need to do the crop.  You need to ensure that you Javascript is indeed passing the correct values in.  I haven't tested it, let me know if it works ;)

Comment: Have you changed your overload to match the new values and corrected your jQuery `showCoords(c)` values to match correctly?  If not, do it.  If you have, in what way is it wrong, is it cropping at all, is it causing an Exception, is it portrait instead of landscape??

Comment: I haven't changed anything in view or javascript code, I simply updated the code in controller with your code. Image is cropping but not accurately.

Comment: No, because you're not passing in the values correctly.  Change the action result to accept `HttpPostedFileBase file, int x, int y, int x2, int y2` and update your `showCoords(c)` and form to pass in the correct values to the correct variables.

Comment: Sadly it's not the same.  You are passing `Top` in as your first parameter into `Crop()`, when in your JavaScript `Top` represents the `y` coordinate.  It shouldn't, it should be `x` as in my code `var top = x;` and `var img_cropped = img.Crop(top,` ...

Comment: I changed it, still no luck. :(

Comment: What code have you got now?  and in what way is it the crop wrong?

Comment: Your `bottom` value is wrong still... it's currently `y2` when it should be `x2`.  Why can't you update the naming within your action and then it will be crystal clear, instead of what it is now which is confusing.  At no point is `bottom` the correct name for a coordinate.

Comment: It's like if I select the face in the image, the top-left corner of the image is cropped after uploaded.

Comment: Ahh yes, the face.  I remember the face on your specific image :o). (Joke) Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I have corrected the values, I have got axies the wrong way around.  I managed to correct it by seeing the values change in [this example](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler)

Comment: Please check my updates, this is what I'm facing right now, I've updated my code again as your latest response. If I'm still wrong, please point me. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'd go through each of the calculations and do a sanity check as to whether they look right to you.  If you choose to crop around 5-10 pixels from the top left hand corner, are the calculated crop values for `top` and `left` calculated as 5-10?

Comment: If I do it manually then yes it is, since I maintained the same serial `"top, left, bottom, right"` in controller and view both. Please be advised that, the image size showing in the page is not the actual size, check my post and check the "View" section. Could it be for this reason?